# MapFish installation "setuptools failed with error code 1"

Tags: installation, windows, mapfish

I am trying to install mapfish on windows7. When i run the commands then it gives error

" -- always-copy -U setuptools failed with error code 1.

I am getting following errors when installing mapfish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you were using an archived installation process for mapfish. The following links should provide everything you need to get mapfish up and running.

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/
https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish/wiki/HowToInstallMapFishWithPip

Basically, the steps are as follows:

1. Install pip with apt-get:

   > ```
   > apt-get update
   > apt-get -y install python-pip
   > curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
   > python get-pip.py
   > ```
2. Download a recent version of virtualenv (You can get the most current version of virtualenv from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This links to the most current as of Jan 05, 2017

   > ```
   > cd /tmp
   > wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/d4/0c/9840c08189e030873387a73b90ada981885010dd9aea134d6de30cd24cb8/virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
   > tar xvzf virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
   > ```
3. Create a disribute-based virtual environment:

   > python virtualenv-15.1.0/virtualenv.py --no-site-packages --distribute
   >   env
4. Activate the virtual environment:

   > source env/bin/activate
5. Install MapFish:

   > pip install mapfish